# Would an "extract answer" edit be useful?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

Scenario: User asks question. Answers given (or not) and are voted on (or not) but not accepted. [User proposes answer or workaround in their *own* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668078/can-i-insert-nodes-into-a-treeview-during-afterlabeledit-without-beginning-to-edi) (either as part of the original post, or in subsequent edits) rather than in an answer with a self-accept.

Would it be desirable or useful for those of some level of reputation to have the ability to extract the answer out of the question, place it into an answer, and then mark it as "accepted answer"? Note, [I do not mean make this the job of a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period).

Perhaps this could be allowed with author permission, or after a time period (rep of X + time of Y).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a real use for this feature.  If the data is there, it really doesn't matter whether the answer is accepted or not.  I'd prefer that the author use the ability to answer and self-accept, but I don't think it's important enough to grant the ability to override the author's actions in this regard.

Comment: Good point. If it's there it's there. I was hoping a quick scroll to the answer without fully reading the question. But I suppose I should be diligent! After all it irks me when people don't read my emails fully :)

Answer (score 1):

I would be against it. The power to choose the accepted answer on some else's question?  I can just see that going wrong.

Comment: That's true I suppose it could. It would be nice if authors would "close" out their questions in general.