# Post not marked as answer, even if it got many answers

Tags: feature-request, questions, accepted-answer, moderator-abilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period)

I have seen many questions that have answers, but not even a single post is marked as answer.

It will be good if the moderators have privilege to mark answers

or

is there already a feature like that

Comment: It's been suggested before - [Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period) - and it's still a bad idea now. Read the previous answers to learn why...

Comment: In fairness, it hasn't been `[status-declined]`... but it doesn't seem to have very good community acceptance either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some question might have many answers but nothing is accepting because nothing meets the asker's needs, or it might be that several answers are acceptable and the asker does not want to choose just one.

If it makes you feel better once question has an up voted answer it no longer appears on the unanswered list.