# Let new-comers know what they should know

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, stack-overflow, answers

I would like to focus two things here:

1. Neither the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), nor [Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), shows [What the question poster should when someone answers their question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) which most of the new comers often don't know about.
2. Neither [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) nor [Accepted Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) tells you that two answers cannot be accepted (which most new-comers try to, resulting in the best answer being 'un-ticked').

---

1. I've seen a lot of questions where answering users had to comment the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to let know the new-comer,that there is a provision to tick the answer, which helped him. This either should be shown (redirected to) when a user posts his first question or when the user get an answer for his first question.
2. I came by this, when today, for the 4th time, I experinced an 'un-tick'. So I asked the user, "Did my answer go wrong". For the four cases, thankfully, they replied that they thought they could tick 2 answers, because both helped, and they wouldn't love one to be sad for not getting a tick (they thought so). So the new-comers need to know about acceptance restriction (*Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem* doesn't mean that only one answer can be chosen ) so that the best answer isn't stripped from the reward of +15.

---

Suggestion:
[image]

Comment: The first things the tour explains are upvotes and accept votes, so the first point is wrong.

Comment: Accepting answers is unimportant. Arguably new users shouldn't know about it.

Comment: @curiousdannii _new users shouldn't know about it_ .That's is wrong, accepted answer shows that they helped the current user

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main thing we need people to do is ask good on-topic questions. That in itself is often pretty hard.

To define acceptance as something a first time poster "must know" surely isn't right. If they figure it out, fine. If not good answers will attract upvotes anyway. We do need to avoid appearing to badger new contributors to do things that really aren't critical.

Acceptance is overrated anyway, the person asking the question is one of the least likely people to know what a good answer looks like. After all, self answers aside, they didn't know enough about the subject to be able to answer it themselves.

So concentrate on writing good answers and worry less about that single accept on them, the upvotes should eventually count for much much more as they are unlimited.

Comment: *Acceptance is overrated anyway*. Opinion, not fact.

Comment: Many people see it as an indicator of a correct answer rather than what it actually is. There are dozens of posts on all metas where the poster has such a misconception. E.g [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115263/feature-request-moderator-ability-to-accept-an-answer) and all its duplicates. So yes, they are all overrating the importance of acceptance. Adding lots of links would make the answer too wordy though.

Comment: But isn't that just a symptom of it being used inconsistently, because many new users are unclear or misunderstand what it's supposed to be for? Feels like you're saying "We shouldn't fix that because it's broken"

Comment: Also, re. *"The main thing we need people to do is ask good on-topic questions"* - sure, that should be the focus *before* a user asks a question, but that's no reason not to give situationally-relevant info to a user *after* they've asked a question which got an answer.