# Hey I just lost 350 points for "Serial upvoting reversed"

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

What is this? Can we please have some way of receiving an explanation? This seems like a system to punish people for leaving too many good answers. Although I did receive a lot of upvotes in a short time, I assume that reflects someone's genuine approval.

Comment: uh... this is something that's been in place from the very beginning; it's just now being made public. Next time, hope that they upvote others too.

Comment: Someone voted *thirty-five times* on you, and you think that's legit? (minimum 35 times)

Comment: Who are 'they'? Why are their votes considered illegitimate?

Comment: @AndrewBarber To be fair, once triggered, _all_ votes from A to B since the beginning of time are reversed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Why wouldn't it be legitimate? Perhaps more interestingly, why would anyone target my account for two days of upvoting?

Comment: @Andrew 35 times *can* be legitimate - it depends entirely on context

Comment: He has a point. What if someone had read his answers long ago and promised himself to reward the guy eventually? He finally got around to making an account and decided to return the favor. That's perfectly legit.

Comment: @Marcin If you look at the upvotes you received, a lot of them are given on different questions within seconds of each other over a periods of several minutes. That's most likely not normal voting behavior. As for why...we can only guess.

Comment: @MarcGravell et al: from my understanding, since confirmed, it was 35 up votes in just a day or two.

Comment: Lots of upvotes in the same time means **the same person serially upvoting your posts** - and no, it doesn't reflect genuine approval it reflect one single person who want to give you reputation. And as this person can be your friend (even if you didn't invite him) this can be considered as tricking the system.

Comment: @AndrewBarber yes, that might be a problem. But it isn't just the "35" that matters - for example, after a few years I'm pretty sure there's a lot more than 35 votes each way between, say, myself and Jon Skeet. That's all I was saying.

Comment: @MarcGravell: This is going to be the new flavor of trolling--just go and upvote someone alot.  They get lots of rep quick, then its reversed with an unhelpful note in their rep page that's slightly accusatory.  Makes for lots of drama.

Comment: @Won't: I hope you're wrong, but I bet you're not.

Comment: @Marcin: I'm actually hoping I'm right.  Not that I'd use it on anybody.  Nope.

Comment: @Wont this part of the code hasn't change in over 2 years so "new" is dubious

Answer (score 26):

If you mean today, that was an automated check - no individual moderator was involved, but those checks are **very** conservative - and this has triggered twice in a matter of days. If a random user suddenly starts upvoting you overwhelmingly and consistently for a sustained duration, then yes: that will be treated as suspicous. Because it is.

On SO, the emphasis is on *a post*, not *a user*. If suddenly a user upvotes all your answers... that is not normal site activity.

Comment: when I first joined, I know I found some awesome answers, upvoted, and followed other answers from those users out of curiosity (and a desire to learn from the best) -- and voted accordingly, before I found out about the automatic trouble-finding tools.

Comment: @sarnold and as long as you weren't excessive - no harm done.

Comment: I'm not known for "moderation"... :) I'm curious if it is possible to trip the thing just playing FGITW with some other high-quality answerers. There's a handful of guys who hit the same tags I do every day and I know I up-vote those same handful of guys over and over again...

Comment: @sarnold it shouldn't be a problem in regular site usage; I'm pretty sure there's plenty of votes between, say, myself and Jon Skeet

Comment: I just hope it's got some mechanism to account for fanboyism :D

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer if it captures some fanboyism. I'd like it if someone's reputation were a reflection on how much the *community* appreciates their answers and not just one obsessive. It may be useful if SO had a number showing us how many different people contributed to someone's reputation.