# Huge and weird upvoting reversal

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes, serial-voting

Yesterday I faced somebody's angry and have downvoted several times so I asked the support about the reversal for downvotes and they answered that works same way as the upvoting reversal. Nice, but today when I logged in to my account, I have noticed that I received a upvoting reversal of 295 points!!!!(please, let me add more exclamations)!!!!!!!!!!

Here's my reputation board:

[image]

I'm so curious to figure out what was that for.

I have got +8 points for the downvoting reversal, which was five(-10) in fact. And you can count in your hands the upvotes I have received since Aug 16, about 8 I have counted.

Comment: It means that there is somebody who voted up a lot of your posts. There is a system (an automatic script) that detects and reverses this. If you have created a new account and used it to upvote yourself, please stop. It might get you suspended. If you have a friend that is voting lots of your posts up, tell him/her to stop. Voting should be based on the **post**, not the user.

Comment: Seems like when the mods took a look to see if you'd been serially downvoted, they also found that someone had serially upvoted you as well.

Comment: @StephenTG: Mods had nothing to do with it. It's an automated process.

Comment: @AlEverett Fair enough. When the bot took a look, then.

Comment: @Doorknob I have a freind in my workplace. We work togheter on the same projects, when we both have a doubt I post a question, he vote it up(not always, only when we working on it togheter). So this' not based on my user, but on **our** question. That is the difference.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Well, that is not allowed. Please vote on the *post*, not the *user*.

Comment: Although the exact implementation of the serial vote detection algorithm is secret, my experience tells me that the major problem is when your co-worker fails to distribute his/her votes fairly to other users. Yes, it makes sense that he/she would upvote questions from you because they are also helpful to him. Same thing happens to me with posts from experts in related fields, I upvote them a lot. But I also vote on other people's posts in between. I think that's the part your co-worker might be missing. Spread the love and all.

Comment: @CodyGray well, I don't know if the algorithm looks for a vote streak, all that secret purpose maybe is to hide any rule. I don't believe that if you go now and cast 50 upvotes for Jon Skeet he will lose anything. Anyway... nevermind. The test review algorithm isn't that good too that punishes you after almost 600 reviews and one fail test. Things like that make me think in quit this site, what already happened once..

Comment: "DontVoteMeDown" has been voted down.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal so sad.. ='(

Answer (score 9):

You're probably going to want to have this conversation privately with the SO moderation team or the SE team. Let's just say [that votes were invalidated according to established guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: Nice, and if I have been helped by 50 answers of the same user(like Darin or Skeet) and voted up on all of them, the user will lose it?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I don't know (seriously, I'm not just saying that to be coy).

Comment: [Relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124597/hey-i-just-lost-350-points-for-serial-upvoting-reversed#comment334340_124599)