# Should you ask a question asker to accept an answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

What I often see is questions that gets answered where the asker of the question says "thank you this was exactly what I was looking for" in the comments but forgets to mark the answer as accepted/doesn't vote up.

I don't want to be a beggar so I won't beg for it in comments, I see other people ask for accepting the question.

What should you do in such a situation? Where the asker clearly accepted an answer but didn't "accept it".

Should a moderator come in and tag the answer as answered?

[Incrementing in a select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052126/incrementing-in-a-select-statement/19053872#19053872)

Comment: Note that moderator accepted answers have been discussed before and broadly rejected; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period

Comment: This question appears to support telling new users about the accept feature; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat

Comment: @RichardTingle I think the combination of these two links and especially the second answers my question. I tried to look for similar topics but probably due to the wording of the "Nudging" users didn't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The community consensus is to leave it alone.

Don't ask for people to accept - it isn't as important as that. It is an indicator by the question asker that the specific answer was the one most helpful to them.

Some people only ever come on to ask questions, get an answer and then they go away, till the next question. This is OK.

The community indicator for a good answer is upvotes.

> Should a moderator come in and tag the answer as answered?

They can't. And if we end up doing this, it will subvert its meaning.

Comment: I think it's a bit hard to say the community consensus is to leave it alone. I agree that nothing official can/should be done, but I would think the consensus is closer to SeanWMs answer: If you feel like leaving a comment encouraging the OP to accept an answer, do so. I've done it myself a couple of times, but never on my own answer. As said (by Bill the Lizard) in one of the links Richard Tingle links to: `Encouraging them to accept a good answer (even your own) is just teaching them the right way to use the system.`

Answer (score 2):

Moderators [can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period) accept answers and it doesn't seem likely that they ever will.

I frequently notice that new users don't accept answers. I usually add a comment pointing them to [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) because they might not know how. This might be the case here. They've only been a member for 5 days.