# Can a moderator set an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, moderation, abandonment

[How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403967/14731) is a good question with multiple good answers. Unfortunately, the person who asked the question seems to have deleted their account (at least, that's my assumption since their profile is not hyperlinked) so this question will never get an "accepted answer".

What happens in such a case? Can moderators mark an answer as accepted?

I know that technically speaking we don't **need** an answer to get marked as accepted (you'll likely tell me to just vote it up) but I think the question is still valid. How do we "fix" abandoned questions?

Comment: Which is itself a duplicate of "[Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18312/246931)"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They can't. And you explained already it is useless since accepting an answer only means that it was useful to the person who asked the question.

Upvotes mean it was useful to the community, and that is what matters in the end.

Comment: True, and if someone want to say "this was especially useful for me" he can award a bounty. :)