# FAQ answer rankings need help

Tags: discussion, sorting, meta-faq

All too often, I read a faq question, only to find that the answers (and the comments) yield a babbling confusion of conflicting voices. As a *question*, it's great. As a source of the definitive *answer* to the question, it sucks.

Example of the moment is pointed to by: [FAQ inconsistency with video?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4604/faq-inconsistency-with-video).

This effect is amplified because FAQ answers are presented in the same order as all other answers; if you happen to have last clicked on 'active', you get 'active', which may be anything but the consensus.

Seems to me that the 'faq' tag should trigger a policy of 'accepted answer first', and that community mods should be encouraged to nuke comment drama, leaving a nice clean 'here's the canonical question, here's the canonical answer' vibe.

It has been pointed out to me that this item has no accepted answer; the photo meta community referred me to the highest-voted answer. If I were duke, you wouldn't be able to apply the official 'faq' tag-of-approval without accepting an answer.

Comment: But there is no accepted answer to the [FAQ question](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/q/28). If there was one, it would be shown first (unless it's by the question owner). Unfortunately the OP was not seen in a while, and nobody else can accept an answer. Overall, it just seems that Photography mods dropped this ball; this is something for them to sort out. Maybe scrap that question and post another one, where the definitive answer is accepted.

Comment: Oh, that explains a bit.

Comment: To your edit: only moderators can add the [faq] tag; the OP did not do it himself. (See [revision history](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/posts/28/revisions)).

Comment: Yes, of course. I think those mods should have been required to mark an answer as accepted. Who cares what the OP thinks once something is anointed 'faq'?

Comment: But they cannot do it; only the author of a  question can mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: So, that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Mod-acceptance on behalf of OP was [proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18312/) 30-something times over the course of 5 years, and never implemented.

Comment: I wonder if the specific case of faq was ever discussed?